# Add modification of file time stamp column while using glob

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have multiple files in a folder that get modified by users at different times. Every week I go and consolidate them all in to one master file but I need to keep track when the file was modified last time. This is a manual process which I am trying to automate.

I wrote the glob code but cant seem to be able to add a column that would provide modification times from each file in to the master file

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("..\Python_Practice\Book*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
all_data.head()


all_data[time] = time.strftime('%m%d%H%M', os.path.gmtime('file')
```

It doesn't really work and cant find anything on the forums that might do something like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are close, but you need to loop through your files and pass the `os.path.getmtime` into a list. you can then pass these to the index.

The following will

Find all `.xlsx` files

merge them into one list

get the last modified unix time

convert the unix time into a datetime

concat the dataframes into a single one and pass the datetime into the index.

```
    from datetime import datetime 
    allFiles = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
    dfs = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in allFiles]
    keys = [datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime (f)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for f in allFiles]
    frame = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried running the code and it keeps saying that module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry @Alex Gould, at the top of your file put `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: any time my man, you can also reset the index and assign it to a column as your use-case. Keep automating!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the timestamp at the moment each file is processed. You code could become:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("..\Python_Practice\Book*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df['time'] = time.strftime('%m%d%H%M', os.path.gmtime('file')
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
all_data.head()
```